# MATLAB GUI: updating variables to mat file

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-gui

I have program where at the end a GUI is launched. I built it using guide. I load 4 variables from my program into 4 GUI text boxes using a mat file called n.mat (and a pushbutton feature).

In the program

```
n = [nuno, ndue, ntre, nquattro];
save n.mat
```

In the GUI interface pushbutton

```
% --- Executes on button press in upload.
function upload_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to upload (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

S = load('n.mat');

handles.v1 = S.nuno;
handles.v2 = S.ndue;
handles.v3 = S.ntre;
handles.v4 = S.nquattro;

set(handles.initial1,'String',num2str(handles.v1));
set(handles.initial2,'String',num2str(handles.v2));
set(handles.initial3,'String',num2str(handles.v3));
set(handles.initial4,'String',num2str(handles.v4));

guidata(hObject, handles);
```

Then I have other 4 text boxes where I change the value of the variables and save them in another mat file. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly.

In the program (before calling myGUI) I initialize the m vector for the updated variables.

```
nunof = 0;
nduef = 0;
ntref = 0;
nquattrof = 0;
m = [nunof, nduef, ntref, nquattrof];
save m.mat
```

In the program (after calling myGUI) I try and load the m.mat file and extract the variables from it so I can use them in some calculations further in the program.

```
load m.mat;

nunof = m.nunof;
nduef = m.nduef;
ntref = m.ntref;
nquattrof = m.nquattrof;
```

Before this, in the GUI interface 'done' button I try and save my inputs into the m.mat file like this:

```
function done_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to done (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% save the parameters to file

load('m.mat');
m = [nunof, nduef, ntref, nquattrof];
nunof = str2num(get(handles.final1,'String'));
nduef = str2num(get(handles.final2,'String'));
ntref = str2num(get(handles.final3,'String'));
nquattrof = str2num(get(handles.final4,'String'));

save('m.mat','-append');
```

I want to know why this isn't working and how can I change it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `save('m.mat','-append');`. You're missing an option to get to append.

In order to use append you have to declare a filename, the variable and then append.

```
save(filename,variables,'-append')
```

Taken from - https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html

Also, from your code you're not redefining the variables in your m struct.

Comment: Thanks.. I just tried to move `m = [nunof, nduef, ntref, nquattrof];` after the 'nquattrof' definition  and put `save('m.mat','m','-append')` .. I get this error: `Struct contents reference from a non-struct array object.
Error in virtualnet (line 325) <-- my program
nunof = m.nunof;`
also what do you mean by 'Also, from your code you're not redefining the variables in your m struct.' and how can I do that? I'm learning to code.

Comment: Have a think about what it is you're doing in your `done_Callback` function. You first load `'m.mat'`. What is m? Is m already a structure? If it is, then what do you think doing `m = [nunof, nduef, ntref, nquattrof];` will do? Is that the proper way to redefine variables in a structure? Look at the MATLAB documentation for structures and how to access and redefine variables within them.

Comment: I redefined m like this:

`m = struct('f1','nunof','f2','nduef','f3','ntref','f4','nquattrof');` 

but I still get `Reference to non-existent field 'nunof'.`

Comment: Don't use `' '` when defining variables in a structure. `'nunof'` should just be `nunof`.

Comment: I did what you told plus commented the part in the program where I initialize  the m.mat file and it's working now, finally the updated variables are showing in the command window! Thanks a lot!

Comment: One thing I just realized is that the program shows results from the m.mat file from the previous run. If I initialize the m.mat values to 0 before the program reads the GUI, only 0 values will be shown, even before I manually put the values I want to store in m.mat from the GUI. You know how can I by-pass this? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to reset the values to 0 every time?

Comment: I don't and I can change that, I just don't know how to get the m.mat values back from the GUI to the workbase to be processed after I change them in the GUI, all in the same script and at the same run, not that when I run the code I get the values from the previous run, if you get what I'm saying.